# Index files in host and remote machine using PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, indexing, vagrant, phpstorm

I work on a Symfony project using Vagrant. The host machine is using Windows. Due to fact that the request time is very high, I decided to install the vendor files inside the vm and the entire "rest" of the project remains inside the synced folder (`project root => /vagrant`).

Everything is working fine and the request time is under 100ms now. But there is one issue left. I have to install the `vendor` on my Windows machine first and then again in the vm, otherwise PhpStorm is not able to index the files correctly (I know, this is a logical consequence).

So my question is, if it is possible, to host a project on the Windows machine and the files are for example under `"C:\Users\SampleUser\Project\ProjectX"` and the `vendor` is installed under `"/home/vagrant/vendor"` and let PhpStorm index the files of both directories?

Otherwise I will have to live with this one and code completion won't work.

[image: Code completion and indexing not working at the moment]

Or I will have to install the libraries on both machines to improve request time and have a more or less "good" workflow.

I hope, I could explain good enough, what my actual problem is.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly... You have to have your libraries accessible locally (where IDE is running -- IDE should see such path as "local"). Where they be physically located -- it's another issue. If you can have them installed on your VM only and then access it from Windows machine via symlink (for example) then so be it. But ideally you need both on local side as IDE usually requires fast access to source files (otherwise it can have random short slowdowns for no apparent reason when editing files)

Comment: There are many ways how you can "attach" non-project files  (e.g. as `PHP | Include Paths` .. or as Additional Content Root) .. but none of them support network path (unless mounted locally to a separate letter (network drive) or symbolic link of any kind -- in this case IDE sees it as local files and OS handles the actual real path access). In other words -- you cannot tell IDE to use your remote `"/home/vagrant/vendor"` path directly.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for there information. And also for reformatting the question. It's my first one and I'll take care of it in the future.

And yes, you got me right. I also did not think about the possible slowdowns when editing files. This seems to be another argument for the double installation of the `vendor`.

All the best

Comment: P.S. For faster shared folder access (from Vagrant machine to Windows host) -- consider using VMWare (requires actual VMWare Workastation + Vagrant plugin -- both need to be purchased) instead of VirtualBox (which is free .. but has slower network access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same exact problem. Indeed a bummer.

**One possible solution** is to leave the `vendor` folder on the VM and manually copy it to your host machine.

Pros:

- PHPStorm is able to index files

Cons:

- If you add a dependency, you have to copy some parts of the `vendor` folder manually to the host machine

**To those facing the same problem**, I might advise SFTP (Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration in PHPStorm) - files can be transferred without leaving the IDE window. The only thing to do is get the VM box password, which is located at
 `%USERNAME%/.vagrant.d/boxes/your box/box version/virtualbox/Vagrantfile`

**Second solution**: if you are using Virtualbox, you can use `vm.synced_folder` with `type: "virtualbox"` (the sync works both ways, host<->guest), and leave the `vendor` folder in your project (for it to sync all the time).

Pros:

- `vendor` folder always up to date, no manual work

Cons:

- Horrible performance (tested myself)

If you want to use non-virtualbox rsync (`type: "rsync"`), you will not get the ability to sync back from the guest (someone, please correct me if I'm wrong!), so you are left with the 1st solution.

It would be great if we could include the `vendor` folder directly from the VM (using some kind of rsync/symlink magic) to the "Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> include path" list, at least when using VirtualBox, but oh well...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I did later was to keep the vendor inside the vm and shared the directory via samba. Then I included it to the php include path in PhpStorm. But this solution was also not so good. More working on the workaround than on the actual code.

Comment: Yes indeed. Symfony+Vagrant is in need of a better solution.
How is performance with Samba?

Comment: I just shared the vendor folder. Due to the fact that it was still on the vm, and just used for indexing, it was quite good. Another important thing was to keep the cache files on the vm.